# A new Runnable causes a gluon application crash

Tags: java, android, gluon-mobile, javafxports

everybody,
I developed a simple java application which then evolved with the gluon-mobile framework. The application is about the game Forza 4 ( Connect 4 ) ; no problem for the desktop part, but I have some problems for the Android part.
I think the problem happens when I go to start a new Runnable using ExecutorService and the application crashes. I don't understand if the problem is for the Runnable itself or the dependencies or something else.

it seems pointless to me to post lines and lines of code. If you want this is the link to the github repository : 
https://github.com/federaimondi82/Forza4App.git

The following is the "indicted" method:

```
private void avviaGioco(int i) {
        btnBotMe.setDisable(true);
        btnMeBot.setDisable(true);

        this.buttonMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(btn->{
            btn.getValue().setDisable(false);
        });

        if(i==0){
            Match.getInstance().setPlayers(
                    PlayerRegistry.getInstance().getPlayer("bot1").createPlayer(),
                    PlayerRegistry.getInstance().getPlayer("real").createPlayer());
        }
        else {
            Match.getInstance().setPlayers(
                    PlayerRegistry.getInstance().getPlayer("real").createPlayer(),
                    PlayerRegistry.getInstance().getPlayer("bot1").createPlayer());
        }

        this.exec.execute(avvia); //this.exec=Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    }

    Runnable avvia=()->{
        Match.getInstance().playMatch();
    };
```

this small block of code can be found in the GamePresenter file  ( Forza4App/src/main/java/net/studionotturno/views/GamePresenter.java )

the following is the build-gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.17'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

apply plugin: 'eclipse'
eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadJavadoc = true
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'net.studionotturno.MainClassApp'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:glisten-afterburner:1.4.1'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

From terminal, with adb.exe logcat -v threadtime I get a lot of lines and it's not easy to understand something; I don't get exceptions in reference to the packages I created but I often read lines similar to this one: Class com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl failed lock verification and will run slower. ( ....... failed lock verification and will run slower ) how could you modify the code to remove this?

The code below is about when I click the button to start a new game and the application closes; how about that?

```
01-04 23:18:35.577 10198 10316 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
01-04 23:18:35.577 10198 10316 I GLASS   : Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
01-04 23:18:35.680 10198 10198 E FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 2.75, touchXs0 = 793
01-04 23:18:35.689 10198 10316 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
01-04 23:18:35.689 10198 10316 I GLASS   : Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
01-04 23:18:35.689 10198 10316 I System.out: don't add points, primary = -1
01-04 23:18:34.262  2084  2104 E UsbDeviceManager: handle message = 9
01-04 23:18:35.772  2084  5586 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity net.studionotturno/javafxports.android.FXActivity
01-04 23:18:35.784  2084  5586 D ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger
01-04 23:18:35.791 10198 10198 V FXActivity: onPause
01-04 23:18:35.813  2084  9094 D ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: The activity in ApplicationInfo{11283f2 com.google.android.packageinstaller} is now in focus and seems to be in full-screen mode
01-04 23:18:35.813  2084  9094 E ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.DeleteStagedFileOnResult/28
01-04 23:18:35.815   717   750 E ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
01-04 23:18:35.827  3939  3997 D GameBoosterService: onGameStatusChange foreground:ForegroundInfo{mForegroundPackageName='com.google.android.packageinstaller', mForegroundUid=10023, mForegroundPid=9904, mLastForegroundPackageName='net.studionotturno', mLastForegroundUid=10240, mLastForegroundPid=10198, mMultiWindowForegroundPackageName='null', mMultiWindowForegroundUid=-1, mFlags=0}
01-04 23:18:35.830  2084  9094 I Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:286488
01-04 23:18:35.834  2084  2098 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x11 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
01-04 23:18:35.834  2084  2098 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x11 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
01-04 23:18:35.837 10198 10316 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 10198 SIG: 9
01-04 23:18:35.837  2084  9094 D ActivityManager: report kill process: killerPid is:10198, killedPid is:10198
```

Comment: Whenever there is a crash, there is a cause... With your mobile connected to your PC, and with debugging options enabled on your device, go to command line, cd into android SDK/platform tools, and run: `adb logcat -v threadtime`. Then run your app, and find in the terminal the exception that causes the crash, and try to solve it. If you can't, edit your question and post it.

Comment: One easy way to find out is adding `System.out.println()` at given points of your code (near the bits you think are failing), and then look in the console for that output.

Comment: Thank you Jose for answering me so quickly; I modified the post with the "verbose" you asked for.

Comment: I can see that the app is killed, but no sign of exceptions. Did you add the printouts (including some descriptive message in each case)? From the output above, if you see `10198 10316 I GLASS`, it means 10198 is the process id of your app, so you can check all the lines with that id for a more complete output.

Comment: Everything seems to be all right now. The mistake was in a class loader I made in the Main class.

@JoséPereda, since you are one of the engineers who developed Gluon, could you tell me if a gluon-apk can load .java classes in runtime?

Comment: If those Java classes were compiled and bundled with the apk, you could use `Class.forName` to load them, if that is what you mean. Otherwise, post a new question (or modify this one to explain with more detail what you are trying to do).